# How to get ID Level Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called ID_info and the sample data is:

```
Info_ID   Type  Desc
1         S     Secondary
1         V     Vertical
2         U     Uniform
3         I     Industry
3         F     First
```

So I need a column which tells me distinct ID's. The first row of the count should be the number and subsequent rows should be null So my output should be:

```
   Info_ID   Type  Desc        Count_Info_ID
    1         S     Secondary   2
    1         V     Vertical    NULL
    2         U     Uniform     1
    3         I     Industry    2
    3         F     First       NULL
```

Comment: SQL data is inherantly unsorted...is there anything (other than the 'order' its displaying) that says which record is first/second/third?

Comment: Can you leave this type of formatting to the front end instead of trying to force it through sql?

Comment: @Twelfth the order doesn't matter as long as the count is anyone of the row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter, then this should work:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Info_ID) Count_Info_ID, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Info_ID ORDER BY Info_ID) RN
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT  Info_ID,
        [Type],
        [Desc],
        CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Count_Info_ID END Count_Info_ID
FROM CTE
```

[**Here is demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/268ae/1) for you to try.

The results are:

```
╔═════════╦══════╦═══════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Info_ID ║ Type ║   Desc    ║ Count_Info_ID ║
╠═════════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════════╣
║       1 ║ S    ║ Secondary ║ 2             ║
║       1 ║ V    ║ Vertical  ║ NULL          ║
║       2 ║ U    ║ Uniform   ║ 1             ║
║       3 ║ I    ║ Industry  ║ 2             ║
║       3 ║ F    ║ First     ║ NULL          ║
╚═════════╩══════╩═══════════╩═══════════════╝
```